# Radio Button toggle based on other radio button

Tags: jquery

I am needing to setup 4 forms with radio buttons for a competition, I am wanting to set it up that the selections disable other options, so if you selected A for question 1 then option A is disabled in 2,3 and 4.

I have managed to put something together, but my knowledge is limited so its most likely the longest possible way of doing this and am hoping someone know of a simpler method before I start building the 2 extra forms into it.

I setup a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/2Kc6m/2/

HTML:

```
    <form id="answer1" class="radioOptions">
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="A1" name="question1" /> A</div>
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="B1" name="question1" /> B</div>
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="C1" name="question1" /> C</div>
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="D1" name="question1" /> D</div>
</form>
<form id="answer2" class="radioOptions">
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="A2" name="question2" /> A</div>
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="B2" name="question3" /> B</div>
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="C2" name="question3" /> C</div>
    <div class="formInput"><input type="radio" value="D2" name="question2" /> D</div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
    $('.answerOptions').click(function(){
   if(this.value == 'A1' && this.checked){
       $('input[value=A2]').prop('disabled', true);
       $('input[value=B2], input[value=C2], input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', false);
   }
   else if(this.value == 'B1' && this.checked){
       $('input[value=A2], input[value=C2], input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', false);
       $('input[value=B2]').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   else if(this.value == 'C1' && this.checked){
       $('input[value=C2]').prop('disabled', true);
       $('input[value=A2], input[value=B2], input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', false);  
   }
   else if(this.value == 'D1' && this.checked){
       $('input[value=A2], input[value=B2], input[value=C2]').prop('disabled', false);
       $('input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', true);  
   }   
   else{
      $('.answerOptions').not(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
var radios = $('input[type="radio"]').addClass('answerOptions');

var forms = $('.radioOptions');
$('.answerOptions').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(this.checked){
        var checked = $('.answerOptions:checked', forms);

        radios.prop('disabled', false);
        checked.each(function(i, v){
            var $item = $(v);
            var $form = $item.closest('form');
            var prefix = this.value.substring(0, 1)

            forms.not($form).each(function(i,v){
                var $form = $(v);
                var x = $form.find('input:radio[value^=' + prefix + ']').prop('disabled', true);
            });

        })
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2Kc6m/5/)

Comment: @RemeJuan is there any problem with the solution

Comment: little one, its only working with 2 sets at a time, working with it in an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2Kc6m/7/

Comment: thanks a lot, that works great, now to learn all this stuff. Will eventually get there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **switch** instruction :

```
$('.answerOptions').click(function () {
    if (this.checked)
        switch (this.value) {
            case 'A1':
                $('input[value=A2]').prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[value=B2], input[value=C2], input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', false);
                break;

            case 'B1':
                $('input[value=A2], input[value=C2], input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[value=B2]').prop('disabled', true);
                break;
            case 'C1':
                $('input[value=C2]').prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[value=A2], input[value=B2], input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', false);
                break;
            case 'D1':
                $('input[value=A2], input[value=B2], input[value=C2]').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[value=D2]').prop('disabled', true);
                break;
            default:
                $('.answerOptions').not(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
                break;
        }
});
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/2Kc6m/3/).